# oozie shell script to execute beeline in kerberos cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, oozie

I have been trying to execute a shell script that consists of beeline to execute hive queries.
The cluster is a Kerberos enabled cluster.
I am able to execute if script has kinit with keytab and principal.
I would like to achieve it with the help of hive2/hcat credentials.

```
<workflow-app name="Table check" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
  <credentials>
    <credential name="hive2" type="hive2">
      <property>
        <name>hive2.jdbc.url</name>
        <value>${jdbcURL}</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hive2.server.principal</name>
        <value>${principal}</value>
      </property>
    </credential>
  </credentials>
    <start to="shell-85ec"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="shell-85ec" cred="hive2">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <exec>test_table.sh</exec>
              <argument>${jdbcURL}</argument>
              <argument>table1</argument>
            <file>/user/hue/test_table.sh#test_table.sh</file>
        </shell>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

When I try to execute it via oozie shell action with credentials I get the following error

```
20/05/10 18:51:50 [main]: ERROR transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271) [hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37) [hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52) [hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49) [hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) [?:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875) [hadoop-common-3.0.0-cdh6.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49) [hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:229) [hive-jdbc-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:184) [hive-jdbc-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107) [hive-jdbc-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) [?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) [?:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:145) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:209) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1617) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1512) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:56) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execCommandWithPrefix(BeeLine.java:1290) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:1329) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.connectUsingArgs(BeeLine.java:864) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.initArgs(BeeLine.java:768) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:1004) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:526) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:508) [hive-beeline-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:313) [hadoop-common-3.0.0-cdh6.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:227) [hadoop-common-3.0.0-cdh6.3.2.jar:?]
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:162) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:189) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
```

Please help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

-a delegationToken beeline comamnd line argument is required for beeline to use delegation token provided by credentials. 
sample command used in she  script

beeline -u "$jdbcUrl" -d org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver -a delegationToken -e "show databases "

Comment: Hi @Madhu your problem is similar to my problem can you please tell me how you run hive in Kerberos in kinit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327262/getting-delegation-token-can-be-issued-only-with-kerberos-or-web-authentication

Comment: Hi if you are trying to run hive queries via oozie shell action, use hive2 credentials and make sure to use delegation token in hive queries. Beeline query I have used in my shell script is given above